# Picker view position on iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, resize

I'm testing app on my iPhone 4s and I have problem with picker view position on screen.
This is a screenshot that show you where I placed picker view on storyboard:

http://i40.tinypic.com/2n1z8eh.png

The problem is when I run it on device and the picker view isn't in that position but a part is out of the bottom screen.

What is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I could think of two issues here:

1- Are you using iPhone4 screens on your storyboard?

2- This can be an autolayout issue, try to set the position in the viewDidLayoutSubviews delegate function in your controller.

Need any more help, just let me know ;D

Answer (score 0):

Your storyboard is currently set to an iPhone 5 screen size so you need to account for the height difference using either:

1.) Autosizing

or

2.) Programmatically changing the picker's frame when the view loads on an iPhone with a screen height not equal to 568.0f

Comment: How do I set autosizing?